# message_runtime in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: ros-melodic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, when we need to declare message_runtime and geometry_msgs in the part catkin_package() in CMakeLists.txt ?
For example:

```
catkin_package(
 INCLUDE_DIRS include
 LIBRARIES beginner_tutorials
 CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs sensor_msgs geometry_msgs message_runtime
 DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349111/message_runtime-in-cmakelists.txt/) by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2020-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @N.N.Huy,

The term `CATKIN_DEPENDS`  refers to other catkin projects that your project depends on, thus if you not fullfil all dependencies the package will not be compiled and/or installed in your machine.

Knowing that, when you place the `geometry_msgs`, it means that in some part of your source files you are going to use a definition that is implemented in that particular package, like the msg types: `Point`, `Twist`, `Pose` etc.

In the same way, `message_runtime` is a package used for build-time dependencies to generate language bindings of messages. This means that is the package in charge of compiling and generating all the needed files when you add a custom msg type, service, action etc. in your package. Hence, when you have in your package a custom msg type, you will need to include the `message_runtime` dependency in order to tell `Catkin` and `Cmake` that your projects contains custom types and it needs to compile all headers and files for you to ble able to include those in your code.

You can find more information about Catkin and `message_runtime` [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt).

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [N.N.Huy](https://answers.ros.org/users/52680/n.n.huy/) on 2020-04-15**:
Thank you so much :) !